# VBA to remove commas in a cell and paste the cell values in different rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have excel data as shown below in X Codes . X code column  has data in diffrent rows. What I need to achieve is as shown in the X Codes(result).

X codes

```
2222, 3333, 4444, 5555    
3458, 4532, 5463, 8976, 4538, 3244, 4538    
2222, 4532,  3243, 3243 , 3243,  EE44    
WW21, EE33, 4532, 5690, 4573, 6758
```

X codes(result)

```
2222    
3333    
4444    
5555    
3458    
4532    
5463    
8976    
4538    
3244    
4538    
2222    
4532    
3243    
3243    
3243    
EE44    
WW21    
4532    
5690    
6758
```

[image]

Comment: You will need to loop through the cells in column A and split each cell on the `,` then loop through that array and paste each value into the next available cell in column C.  See what you can do with that information, try to write the code yourself then when you get stuck come back with the code and tell us where you are stuck and we will help overcome that specific problem.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a loop-less solution using arrays; join the cells with commas, then split them back:

```
Sub joinThenSplit()
    Dim ar: ar = Sheet3.Range("A2", Sheet3.Range("A999999").End(xlUp)).Value2
    ar = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(ar), ","), ",")
    Sheet3.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(ar) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(ar)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To further elaborate on Scott's suggestion, use the Split command. For example

```
    Sub Example()
        Dim SomeValue As String
        Dim SplitValue As Variant
        Dim ToSheet As Variant

        SomeValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value

        SplitValue = Split(SomeValue, ", ")

        ' SplitValue should now look something like:
        ' SplitValue(0) = "2222"
        ' SplitValue(1) = "3333"
        ' SplitValue(2) = "4444"
        ' SplitValue(3) = '5555"

        ' Now you can easily put these values into the next available spot on your sheet
        ' Here I use Range("C1000000") because it is very close to the max row count
        ' There are other ways of doing this as well.

        ' What is happening in the code below is I am finding my next entry location, and then
        ' resizing this to include the number of additional rows I need (the max dimension of
        ' the splitvalue array + 1 since Split creates 0 based arrays)

        ' I use a second array that is 2D so that I can directly assign the values from the array to the sheet range
        ' instead of assigning each cell value individually
        ReDim ToSheet(1 To UBound(SplitValue) + 1, 1 To 1)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(SplitValue) To UBound(SplitValue)
            ToSheet(i + 1, 1) = SplitValue(i)
        Next
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C1000000").End(xlUp).Resize(UBound(ToSheet)).Value = ToSheet
End Sub
```

This should get you headed in the right direction. This wont do all of it for you, but see if you can figure out how to use this as a framework for building the routine you need. Split is a super useful function, and used with a loop could give you exactly what you need.

Best of luck.

Comment: When I run this I get 4 cells containing 2222.

Comment: Try it now. It wasnt working before since SplitValue was a 1D array.

Comment: @BrandonBarney: Thanks! Works perfectly. Just a doubt  - suppose the FIRST row contains values separated by comma and SECOND row with only one value, the THIRD row again with values separated by comma. In that case, the code only works for the FIRST ROW. How can we traverse to the third row?

Comment: @tyler In the code above I am using a static range ("A2") to determine where the values are coming from. Your task will be to take the less-dynamic portions of the example above, and fix it to suit your needs. There are a few approaches you can take with this, but I would suggest watching some tutorials that deal with dynamic ranges and the like.